# Css, hover each area separately

Tags: css, html, hover, drawing

Hi i try to draw something like this :

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXRVe.jpg)

using divs and css, i need to hover each area separately.
so far I've done something like this but it does not work well because it activates blocks and only two of it ;/
css :

```
 <style type="text/css">


    .arrow-up {

      position : absolute;
      top : 150px;
      width: 150px; 
        height: 0; 
        border-left: 60px solid transparent;
        border-right: 60px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 60px solid black;
    }
  .arrow-up:hover{
    border-bottom: 60px solid red;
}

    .arrow-down {
       position : absolute;
      top : 90px;  
      width: 150px; 
        height: 0; 
        border-left: 60px solid transparent;
        border-right: 60px solid transparent;

        border-top: 60px solid blueviolet;
    }
    .arrow-down:hover{
    border-top: 60px solid red;
    }
    .arrow-right {
        position : absolute;
       top : 90px;
      width: 0; 
        height: 0; 
        border-top: 60px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;

        border-left: 60px solid green;
    }
    .arrow-right:hover{
    border-left: 60px solid red;
    }

    .arrow-left {
        position : absolute;
       top : 90px;
      left : 217px;
      width: 0; 
        height: 0; 
        border-top: 60px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 60px solid transparent; 
        border-right:60px solid blue; 
    }

    .arrow-left:hover{
    border-right: 60px solid red;
    }
</style>

<html>
    <body>
       <div class="arrow-down"></div>
      <div class="arrow-up"></div>

    <div class="arrow-left"></div>
    <div class="arrow-right"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

any idea ?
is it possible ?

[demo](http://jsbin.com/enisic/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Yea looks pretty good. Remove the div:hover selector and use your classes to select the elements hover. So:

```
.arrow-up:hover{
    border-bottom: 60px solid red;
}
```

Will now change the colour of the 'border' to red. Hope this solves the problem

Your positioning:
CSS:

```
.arrowBox{
    display:inline-block;
    width:24%;
    //for ie 5.5 to 7 
    float:left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="arrowBox">
<!-- arrows go in here -->

</div>
```

Comment: it is better, but still if i hover right or left corner of bottom div it's hovering the sides divs :/

Comment: @user1994672 Sorry I don't understand?

Comment: ok if i Hold my cursor here (see link), the right div is hovered :/

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/48125183/example.png

Comment: @user1994672 I see! that's a tricky one. It's because the Divs are still there and have transparent borders so they are technically still there. There are ways around it but all I can think of involves difficult javascript to find the position of the mouse in the parent element or to make the shapes in a canvas which is even more difficult. Manipulating the border seems to be the only other way around I can think of. But they wont be straight lines. `border-radius:50%;` will change the borders dramatically! But this isn't the shape you'd need. Sorry

Comment: ok I understand :) if You can just tell me, now when i have ready this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/enisic/4/edit) how Can i put 4 beside in one line ???